# At the first possibility

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality

"At the first possibility" and "at the first opportunity", are those interchangeable? Is option 1 grammatically correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 is not correct. The two words do not mean the same thing and are not interchangeable.

- An 'opportunity' is a specific time, occasion or situation in which something can be done.
- A 'possibility' is a *chance* that something could happen.

For example, if someone asked you to do something by the end of the day and you *knew* that you had the time and means to do it, you might say "I have an opportunity to do it". However, if you were *not sure* whether or not you had the time or means to do it, you might say "there is a possibility I could do it". You could even say "there is a possibility I might have an opportunity"!

Having said this, the word "chance" can sometimes mean either opportunity *or* possibility, and this could be interchangeable. For example:

- I haven't had the opportunity to do it
- I haven't had the chance to do it.